# mocking connection.db.collection('collection_name') with Jest

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I have been banging my head against the same wall for a day now - what have I missed? I am sure that I used to know how to do this!

`arr` is always empty.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

 it('mocking test', async () => {
        jest.mock('mongoose');
        
        mongoose.connection.db.collection('test').find = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(
            Promise.resolve([
                {
                    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('77f6803bdd3e32292f4e4977'),
                    data: 'something',
                },
                {
                    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('88f6803bdd3e32292f4e4988'),
                    data: 'another thing',
                },
            ]),
        );

        const result = await mongoose.connection.db.collection('test').find()
        const arr = await result.toArray()
        expect(result).toBeDefined()
        expect(arr).toHaveLength(2)
    });
```

This is obviously NOT the real test code, just the minimal example of my current approach not working.

(P.S. please don't suggest using a model, the real application is legacy code whose mongo aggregate queries I do NOT want to disturb).

(P.P.S. not going to use an in-memory server either, I want totally independent unit tests)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out or find a workaround?

Comment: I ended up using Mockingoose. But I reckon I missed.exec() on the end of the `.find`